TypeError: mercadopago.configure is not a function
Estoy enfrentando un problema con la integración de Mercado Pago en mi backend. Al intentar configurar Mercado Pago en mi aplicación Node.js, recibo un error que dice TypeError: mercadopago.configure is not a function. Parece que la función configure no se está reconociendo como válida en la instancia de mercadopago.
He seguido los pasos de la documentación oficial de Mercado Pago para Node.js, incluyendo la importación de la librería y la configuración del acceso token. Aquí está el código relevante en mi index.js:
    const mercadopago = require('mercadopago');

mercadopago.configure({
    access_token: 'MI_ACCESS_TOKEN'
});

Ya he probado a actualizar a la última versión de la librería, desinstalar y volver a instalar, pero el problema persiste. He verificado que mi token de acceso sea válido y que no haya errores en la instalación de la librería mercadopago.
¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema?

Puede que esto ya este outdated mercadopago.configure sugiero revisar el repo de github y verificar que se este siguiendo la sintaxis correcta tal como lo sugiere el colega @fast

Hola el error nose a que se pueda deber, pero te recomiendo usar de ejemplo el proyecto realizado en github que te proporciona mercadopago para corroborar de que tengas todo igual, espero que te  sirva de ayuda.

Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, este puede ser un excelente comentario, sugiero eliminar la respuesta y agrega el comentario en la pregunta.

Bienvenido y gracias por tu aporacion. Cuando no tengas una respuesta, puedes colaborar dejando un comentario. Secundo la sugerencia del compañero g.4
